# Regular Expression wrong match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying a regex to validate an Url.

```
var url = "https://www,google.com";
var urlRegex = /(https|http)?:\/\/(?:\w[\-\w.]+)(?:\/[\-\w+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(?:\?[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?/i;
var result = urlRegex.test(url);
```

so i am getting "result" as true but i should get false as "url" contains comma.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

Add anchors (`^` for beginning of a string, and `$` for the end of the string):

```
^(https|http)?:\/\/(?:\w[\-\w.]+)(?:\/[\-\w+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(?:\?[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?$
^                                                                                                ^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zL6rE0/2)

Comment: You are welcome. If you need to find URLs inside a larger text, you'd need to use `\b` around your pattern, and add a negative look-ahead in the beginning: `(?!\S*,\b)`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting true since your regex partly matches.

Use `^(https|http)?:\/\/(?:\w[\-\w.]+)(?:\/[\-\w+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(?:\?[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?$`

instead.